# Kubernetes - Stateful set mysql - How does it sync?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I'm going through [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4Z7visMM4E) and they said in a `statefulset` setup, `Master is the only one with read-write access and worker pods sync with master and when new worker pod starts it syncs with the previous slave pod.`

Does that mean we have to configure the mysql replication on the first slave mysql pod to sync with master just like normal setup? And how does the new worker pod syncs with previous slave pod?

[image]

Comment: Not really clear to me what you are looking for , but I believe helm chart for the same can do all the basic configuration for you, incase needed to configure you can do easily by playing with values.yaml,  master slave headless would be already configured.

Comment: At first I thought it does data replicas like copying from other pod volume to this but that doesn't make sense. So it has to be the mysql service that does the replication. If that is the case, I'm guessing the new slave pod need to have per-built in mysql  config that says to sync with the previous pod instead of master. Is that correct?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, it is about setting up and configuring a complex database setup. The DBA sister site offers help in questions like this, not the programming focused SO.